# can't mock an exception with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.7, pytest-mock

I do not seem to be able to test a getopt exception. A very simplified example is here (the main file):

```
import sys, getopt

def main():
    try:
        options, _ = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'h')
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print("here I want to go")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the test file where I am trying to raise the GetoptError exception is here (the test file):

```
import getopt, mock, main

@mock.patch("getopt.getopt", mock.MagicMock(side_effect=getopt.GetoptError('')))
def main_test():
    try:
        main.main()
        assert False
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        assert True
```

Unfortunately no exception is raised. The test returns:

```
    @mock.patch("getopt.getopt", mock.MagicMock(side_effect=getopt.GetoptError('')))
    def main_test():
        try:
            main.main()
>           assert False
E           assert False

main_test.py:7: AssertionError
```

Can anybody point out what I am missing? Thank you.

Comment: `import mock` -- which version of Python that is? `mock` is in standard library since 3.3 as `unittest.mock`.

Comment: Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul 21 2019, 14:43:25)
[GCC 7.4.0] on cygwin

Comment: You are catching the exception in the `main` function so pytest will never be able to detect that it occurred. How to workaround this is not easy to tell from your example. Maybe move the try/except clause to `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: @tmt, that's it. I did not think about that. Now I know how to tackle it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BerndPrager Cool. Use `with pytest.raises` from the other answer as the correct way of asserting exceptions in pytest.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `with pytest.raises` for testing exceptions:

```
def main_test():
  with pytest.raises(getopt.GetoptError)  as err:
     main.main()
```

Refer pytest assert for http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html

Comment: E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'getopt.GetoptError'>